# Late Answers review queue is full of old answers!

Tags: discussion, review

I just popped into the review queues and noticed that the Late Answers queue has **way** more answers included than I would have expected:

[image: review counts]

On digging into the queue I quickly noticed that I was seeing answers added multiple years ago.

I can't be certain but I'm pretty sure these weren't in the queue prior to the site redesign. Not sure if this is a bug with how recent answers are getting flagged, or if this is an intended change for answers that haven't gotten a certain number of reviews?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was a deliberate one-time increase. In the future, there will simply be a slightly higher rate of posts being added to that queue.

---

The reputation threshold for bypassing the late answer queue was recently raised from 10 to 50. The newly queued posts are ones which *would* have gone into the queue when they were posted, but the user had over 10 (but less than 50) rep.

See [Can we raise the bar for reputation for late answers to enter the review queue?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/266696/can-we-raise-the-bar-for-reputation-for-late-answers-to-enter-the-review-queue) for full context. (I think the title is supposed to say bypass instead of enter?)

So... review away! There are probably plenty of iffy answers that slipped past us the first time. Plus you might get badges.

Comment: The hard part there is that there seems to be a threshold on how many reviews you can actually do. The current backlog means that you'd need 20 users to fill their full daily quota to get the cueue cleared.

Comment: @RichardtenBrink It's fine if it takes more than a day! But we do have a *lot* of users with [enough reputation (500) for that queue](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/access-review-queues) so it's not really unreasonable for it to get done quickly, if enough of them are made aware of it.

Comment: And are they made aware of it? :)

Comment: @RichardtenBrink As best as possible - there's a pinned message in chat, and this question is featured, so it's linked in the sidebar on meta. That means more awareness than usual of review queues. There've been 137 reviews today, so as long as that's kept up it'll be clear in reasonable time, and they were mostly before I posted those links so it could even speed up if more people notice.

Comment: I should clarify that **"deliberate"** means this is a well-known, temporary issue. The change took effect going back to the start of the site, but once all the current reviews are completed, the effect of the change should be only a few extra answers on the queue every now and then. It should not be a continual flood of tasks like you see here.

Comment: And the queue is back to normal now, mostly thanks to I think 5-10 users reviewing their quota every day the last few days.